# REST webservice 404 not found

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, weblogic

When invoking a webservice deployed in a weblogic server I get a 404 - Not found error. Even after searching for similar questions in SO i wasn´t able to find a solution:

[Rest Web services returning a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501665/rest-web-services-returning-a-404)

[Java Restful Service eclipse tomcat HTTP Error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767165/java-restful-service-eclipse-tomcat-http-error-404)

[Restful Web Service returning 404, bad web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828820/restful-web-service-returning-404-bad-web-xml)

The resources are correctly deployed in the weblogic server as you can see from the following image:

[image]

I have the following code:

**ServicesREST.java**

```
package pt.vdf.nc.webproxy;

@Path("/NCProxyServices")
public class ServicesREST {

    public ServicesREST(){
        WebProxy.getAllInstances();
    }

    @Path("ManageShortNumber/{MSISDN}/{DestinationNumber}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response manageShortNumberSMSIntegration(@PathParam("MSISDN") String terminal, @PathParam("DestinationNumber") Integer shortNumber) {
    (...)
   }
```

**application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
    version="5">
    <description>WebApp builder and deployer</description>
    <display-name>ncwebproxy</display-name>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>ncwebproxy.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/webproxy/</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

**web.xml**

```
(...)

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Administrators</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>webproxy</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/webproxy/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>

(...)
```

**[EDIT]** -> Added pom.xml below:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>services-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>services-web</name>
    <description>Services Web - WAR</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>pt.vdf.nc.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../services</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <war.phase>package</war.phase>
        <install.phase>install</install.phase>
        <weblogic.version>10.3.6</weblogic.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>env-loc-wl</id>

            <properties>
                <war.phase>package</war.phase>
                <install.phase>install</install.phase>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>env-loc-tc</id>

            <properties>
                <war.phase>none</war.phase>
                <install.phase>none</install.phase>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>env-dev-wl</id>

            <properties>
                <war.phase>package</war.phase>
                <install.phase>install</install.phase>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>env-tst-wl</id>

            <properties>
                <war.phase>package</war.phase>
                <install.phase>install</install.phase>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>env-ath-wl</id>

            <properties>
                <war.phase>none</war.phase>
                <install.phase>none</install.phase>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>env-prd-wl</id>

            <properties>
                <war.phase>package</war.phase>
                <install.phase>install</install.phase>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <finalName>ncservices</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>cfg/services-cfg.properties</include>
                    <include>ctx/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>${war.phase}</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-install</id>
                        <phase>${install.phase}</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>services-common</artifactId>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
            <version>${weblogic.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.timesten</groupId>
            <artifactId>ttjdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>wlclient</artifactId>
            <version>${weblogic.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.11</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried a variety of different url patterns to try and invoke the service successfully but i keep getting the error 404.

```
http://localhost:7001/webproxy/NCProxyServices/ManageShortNumber/9842987982/97668/
http://localhost:7001/pt.vdf.nc.webproxy/webproxy/NCProxyServices/ManageShortNumber/9842987982/97668/
http://localhost:7001/NCProxyServices/ManageShortNumber/9842987982/97668/
```

Would you kindly point me in the right direction to successfully invoke this service.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I see no class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`, no Jersey configuration in your web.xml at all? (edit: removed the reference to a `beans.xml`, I see Spring is used)

Comment: See in your logfiles if you have deployment problems

Comment: @Gimby Jersey configurations exist on the pom.xml which I added to my question. Not sure what you mean by "I see no class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application"

Comment: @Jens The deployment was completed successfully with no errors or problems.

Comment: @DanielAndré the jersey user guide is rather specific. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/jax-rs.html#d4e186

Comment: Might remove the * from your url-mapping in web.xml; this thread may shed more light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732/invalid-url-pattern-servlet-mapping-in-tomcat-6-0/26744#26744

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) but reading the parameter using @PathParam and not from JSON format. Also I see @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) but the method return type is Response. Can you try removing these two annotations. And in case you need to handle JSON requests/responses you need to specify JSON library for encoding & decoding. Not sure if you have taken care of that already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately removing the two notations made no difference. As for handling JSON requests/responses, it's not an issue.

Comment: Could you please post the complete web.xml file.

Comment: By the way, normally 7001 is the admin port of weblogic and managed server port is 8001, although you could configure these port numbers. Just thinking should we try with 8001 - http://localhost:8001/webproxy/NCProxyServices/ManageShortNumber/9842987982/97668/